How to check allowed characters in bash with regex
I want to use regex for checking only three allowed characters: "[0-9]" and "." and "/".
Note: The test case is an ipv4/ipv6 address but I don't want to check the number in the range [0-255], I only want to check allowed characters in the input variable.
I use "|" as the "or" expression, and combine all the three allowed characters with "|", and finally add "+" in the last for make sure at less one allowed character must exist in the input variable.
Here is the test bash script:
test_ipv4_address="127.0.0.1/24"
test_wrong_ipv4_address="127.0.0.1#24"
test_ipv6_address="::1/128"

allowed_characters='([0-9]|\.|\/)+'

[[ "$test_ipv4_address" =~ $allowed_characters ]] && echo "yes, $test_ipv4_address is allowed"
[[ "$test_wrong_ipv4_address" =~ $allowed_characters ]] && echo "yes, $test_wrong_ipv4_address is allowed"
[[ "$test_ipv6_address" =~ $allowed_characters ]] && echo "yes, $test_ipv6_address is allowed"

Here is the output:
yes, 127.0.0.1/24 is allowed
yes, 127.0.0.1#24 is allowed
yes, ::1/128 is allowed

Here is the expected output:
yes, 127.0.0.1/24 is allowed

What's wrong in my regex? And how to fix?

Changing to allowed_characters='([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' which I got from How can I get the IP address IPV4/IPV6 on linux removes the test_ipv6_address, but not the test_wrong_ipv4_address. I.e. only a partial solution.

Your regular expression seems almost correct, but it could use some slight adjustments:

The . character in regex has a special meaning (matching any character), so it needs to be escaped using \. to match literal dots.
You're already escaping . properly, but the key issue is how you're handling regex within bash. Bash treats regex differently than other languages, so double-check how it's applied.

Now the modified script will look something like this:
test_ipv4_address="127.0.0.1/24"
test_wrong_ipv4_address="127.0.0.1#24"
test_ipv6_address="::1/128"

# Regex to allow only digits, dots, and slashes
allowed_characters='^[0-9./]+$'

# Check if the input matches the allowed characters
[[ "$test_ipv4_address" =~ $allowed_characters ]] && echo "yes, $test_ipv4_address is allowed"
[[ "$test_wrong_ipv4_address" =~ $allowed_characters ]] && echo "yes, $test_wrong_ipv4_address is allowed"
[[ "$test_ipv6_address" =~ $allowed_characters ]] && echo "yes, $test_ipv6_address is allowed"

And you will get an desired output like this:
└─$ ./test.sh 
yes, 127.0.0.1/24 is allowed


The only thing wrong with the OPs script was forgetting to add start and end of string anchors to their regexp. This, as the OP had:
allowed_characters='([0-9]|\.|\/)+'

is testing that at least one of those characters appears anywhere in the string, but other characters could exist in the string too, while this:
allowed_characters='^([0-9]|\.|\/)+$'

would test that every character in the string is one of those characters and no other characters can exist in the string.
It's also unnecessary to escape / as it's not a regexp metachar, and you could just use 1 bracket expression instead of a bracket expression plus alternation (in which case the . no longer needs to be escaped as it's literal inside a bracket expression) which would reduce the regexp to:
allowed_characters='^[0-9./]+$'

With a couple of additional minor modifications to make it easier to enhance in future, the script can be written as:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test_addrs=(
    127.0.0.1/24
    127.0.0.1#24
    ::1/128
)

allowed_characters='^[0-9./]+$'

for addr in "${test_addrs[@]}"; do
    [[ "$addr" =~ $allowed_characters ]] && echo "yes, $addr is allowed"
done


$ ./tst.sh
yes, 127.0.0.1/24 is allowed

